# iOS app crashes sometimes at statup when i run it without computer. How can diagnose this?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, crash

All question you can see in title.
I don't know why it crashes when run without Xcode.
How can diagnose this?
How can get logs?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does startup take longer than 30 seconds sometimes?  If you are starting up your app and you are connected to the debugger springboard will let you app take any amount of time to start up.  If you are not connected to a debugger, springboard will kill your app after 30 seconds.

Comment: i found in log, thats what you mean? -  Application Specific Information:
inc.rb.RAT failed to resume in time

Comment: Thanks it's helpful i found thats because main tread is overload and iOS just kill my app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical access to the device you can pull the logs directly from the device via the Xcode organiser when you next plug it in.

Another option, if you don't have physical access to the device would be to add a library to retrieve crash logs for you, such as [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) which will upload the crash log to a server the next time the application is launched.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in C it means you haven't initialised some memory, somewhere. Thus you'll sometimes have the correct conditions for startup, and other times not. A common case is expecting zero as the starting case for other calculations: if you haven't zeroed the block of memory in question, your process and others have (between this run and the last) written and rewritten that memory so that it will sometimes be zero (thus a successful startup) and other times not.

In your case, you could probably use callgrind to check where the crash is occurring.